# Growing Boost.Interprocess memory mapped file with single writer

Tags: c++, boost, mmap, memory-mapped-files, boost-interprocess

My question is about growing memory-mapped regions with Boost.Interprocess, in the context of a single writer process and multiple reader processes. **Is it OK to use `managed_mapped_file::grow` from the writer, assuming it's acceptable for the readers not to be updated of the change of the map's size?** My assumption is that the reader's maps would stay valid, and then I could remap the readers with the updated size when I need them to pick up the latest changes from the writer. Is this correct?

The [Growing managed segments](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_advanced_features.growing_managed_memory) section of the documentation says:

> Once a managed segment is created the managed segment can't be grown. The limitation is not easily solvable: every process attached to the managed segment would need to be stopped, notified of the new size, they would need to remap the managed segment and continue working. [...]

This makes me think that I can `grow` as long as I'm fine with the readers not being updated right away. However, the documentation goes on saying:

> On the other hand, Boost.Interprocess offers off-line segment growing. What does this mean? That the segment can be grown if no process has mapped the managed segment. If the application can find a moment where no process is attached it can grow or shrink to fit the managed segment. [...] `managed_mapped_file` also offers a similar function to grow or `shrink_to_fit` the managed file. Please, remember that no process should be modifying the file/shared memory while the growing/shrinking process is performed. Otherwise, the managed segment will be corrupted.

This makes me think that I can't do what I want to do, but I don't understand why it would not work.

Comment: Do you want to talk about some more pet-peeves about segment managers vs. shared memory? I have a few more warnings that you might like to know about making design decisions :)

Comment: Yes, I would very much like to know these warnings.

Comment: [Come over](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) if you have the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make a careful distinction between `shared_memory_object` (which is really low-tech and un-imposing) and `managed_shared_memory`/`managed_mapped_file` (which both use a `segment_manager`).

You are using the latter.

---

> "assuming it's acceptable for the readers not to be updated of the change of the map's size":

I don't see how this assumption can hold.

The managed segment constitutes, in essence, an auxiliary memory heap with its associated control structures.

It makes sense for the control structure to include details such as the actual extents of that "heap". Since the control structures are in the shared memory, they must be in the section already mapped into reading processes, too.

Changing the size of the memory segment would change values in that control structure which is visible from all processes mapping the same shared memory. This would obviously wreak havoc in processes that don't actually have enough memory mapped to satisfy the new extents (leading to page faults, at best).

Now, I **can** imagine a very smart implementation that circumvents the need for such control information (like e.g. a classical free block list with a sentinel value). But I don't expect Boost Interprocess to have taken this route¹, and the text you quoted strongly  suggests that the design didn't cater for this kind of flexibility.

> Is it OK to use managed_mapped_file::grow from the writer, assuming it's acceptable for the readers not to be updated of the change of the map's size?

No it's not OK.

> My assumption is that the reader's maps would stay valid, and then I could remap the readers with the updated size when I need them to pick up the latest changes from the writer. Is this correct?

The /maps/ will be fine, no doubt (depending on how `grow` is implemented, but I think I've confirmed this experimentally before). The problem is with the `segment_manager` that operates on top. This is the one that is going to be confused.

¹ pure Fingerspitzengefühl

Comment: Would it be possible to use the first couple of bytes of the shared memory to represent whether the shm has grown or not, then whenever one of the processes grows the shared memory that bytes are set and it indicates that the other process should remap its address space?

Comment: @Iman yes, basically, you should always consider building a wrapper around managed_mapped_* segments for versioning/compatibility. However, just setting the bytes wouldn't signal a thing (that requires [explicit synchronization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html)).

Comment: For production use (beyond disposable cache data) I would probably use a  mapped file to contain metadata (like you suggest) and possibly synchronization primitives in a mapped_region at the start, followed by a managed_external_buffer that could be placed in a subsequent mapped_region. It sounds a little bit tedious, but it removes many problematic edge cases.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on how this can be achieved? I'm having trouble following on how I should use managed_external_buffer since it is not shared between processes. Should I refrain from using managed_shared_memory if I want to grow the shared memory region because it will invalidate all the pointers in other processes?

Comment: You can use managed_external_buffer on any memory buffer, so you can use it in shared memory as well.

Comment: "Should I refrain from using managed_shared_memory if I want to grow the shared memory region because it will invalidate all the pointers in other processes?" - that's not how offset_ptr works. You **can** grow segments without invalidating content. However, you cannot do so safely "online".

Comment: Can you please explain more what you mean by "you cannot do it safely online"? If I grow a memory segment and deallocate the pointer and reallocate it, would it be fine?

Comment: I don't want to reallocate all the mapped pointers at once.

Comment: The only pointers that would be "invalidated" across remapping (with or without changing the size) are raw pointers. You should not have raw pointers to shared memory objects, this is what [offset_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/offset_ptr.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:~:text=This%20feature%20converts%20offset_ptr%20in%20a,in%20different%20addresses%20in%20every%20process.) is for.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It has nothing to do with remapping, since the same mapped segment may already have different addresses in everyt other process to begin with.

Comment: And here's the demo in case code speaks better than words: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7935f229bca5ba7

Comment: @Iman Wrapping it with `managed_external_buffer` inside mapped_regions inside file_mappings becomes... a lot more tedious: https://godbolt.org/z/sfbjWG15P (Coliru seems to not like this, but it could be the sandbox constraints)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the code samples. When I was referring to pointers, I meant when you use `allocate` to get a `void *` pointer. Will they be also valid in addition to the named variables?

Comment: You can't use that with Boost Interprocess. Their allocators return offset_ptr, but regardless, even if you e.g. use Boost Pool inside a shared buffer, you should store these pointers in offset_ptr. Then they will remain valid. The named variables were **not** the offset_ptrs here. The elements in the `Index` instance were (`StringPtr = offset_ptr<string>`). In fact, named objects in managed segments are the alternative, a way to get at your shared object graph's root object conveniently after remap.

Comment: I was using it and I think it was fine. This is how it was documented in the quick start for managed memory segments. But that's good to know that named objects can be used after the grow. https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html

Comment: @Iman Oooh. You used the `allocate` method on the segment manager. That's a different contexst (I never used it before, so I didn't realize it exists in the public interface). However, the linked doc section immediately solves the riddle for you: you can (i.e. have to) use `managed_shared_memory::handle_t` to have a handle from [that] can identify any byte of the shared memory segment even if it is mapped in different base addresses](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:~:text=segment.get_handle_from_address(shptr)%3B)

Comment: Got it thanks! I should have probably created a separate question for it. It has become a very long thread!

Comment: @Iman If you like, you can still post it, and I'll just transfer the answer there with some explanations. That would make it easier for others to find in the future (keywords `managed_external_buffer`, `grow`, shared memory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67236693/grow-managed-shared-memory-in-boost-without-unmapping-all-the-pointers Posted the question here. Sorry for the delay! @sehe

Comment: @Iman cool no worries, nobody here is in a hurry. Or well, nobody should be. Future visitors will still find it after a year, or three. Or ten :)