# grow managed_shared_memory in boost without unmapping all the pointers

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

Is it possible to grow `managed_shared_memory` in boost without having to reallocate pointer addresses created using `allocate` function of `segment_manager`? Ideally, I would like the code below to work safely:

```cpp
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   char *shptr;
   {
      //Create a managed shared memory segment
      managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 1024);

      //Allocate a portion of the segment (raw memory)
      managed_shared_memory::size_type free_memory = segment.get_free_memory();
      shptr = (char *) segment.allocate(1024/*bytes to allocate*/);
      shptr[1023] = 1;

      //Check invariant
      if(free_memory <= segment.get_free_memory())
         return 1;
   }
   {
       managed_shared_memory::grow("MySharedMemory", 500);

       //I don't intend to use the additionally allocated bytes in shptr because
       //it is not possible to support it from OS side.
       assert(shptr[1023] == 1);
       shptr[1023] = 2;

       managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 1024);

       //ability to allocate additional pointers without overriding
       //previous allocations
       char *shptr2 = (char *) segment.allocate(500/*bytes to allocate*/);
       assert(shptr[1023] == 2);
       shptr2[499] = 1;
   }

}
```