# Creating an allocator that uses multiple managed_shared_memory segments in boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

In order to get around growing a [managed_shared_memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html) segment without unmapping and remapping all the previous regions, I want to create an allocator that creates a new managed_shared_memory segment whenever there is not enough space in the previous segments. I have looked into the [boost interprocess node allocators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html) but they don't seem like a good fit for this problem. Is there any class or utility in boost that can help with this problem?

Comment: An allocator would ideally *not* use a managed segment, but a mapped region. That's because managed segments exist for the entire purpose of managing allocations. That said, you can use any allocator that accepts a user-allocator, in which case you will have to provide the glue to optionally allocate more shared memory when needed.

Comment: My $0.10: Just create a 10TB shared segment/mapped region. Only dirty pages will ever be committed/reserved anyways

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the response. Do you know any implications of large mapped regions that I need to be aware of? Any performance cost?

Comment: It might not work well with 32 bit kernels or kernels lacking large page support. That's about it for now. Of course, you might run into trouble if you actually overcommit and the pages are not disk-backed

Comment: Looks like for newer versions of boost it is not possible to do this since Boost uses posix_fallocate which consumes equivalent physical memory as the shared memory region. This means that you cannot allocate more than your available physical RAM.

Comment: fallocate deals with disk space. I do this all the time. You could create a minimal self-contained tester and we can compare notes.

Comment: I created a godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/fKb667TPG. I ran this code inside docker using the `--shm-size 100G` flag. I'm monitoring the ram usage using htop and it uses 30Gb of RAM when using Boost 1.76. If I use the Boost that is shipped by default in Ubuntu the memory usage doesn't increase at all.

Comment: If I use 40GB the program will throw a boost exception:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception'
  what():  No such file or directory
Aborted

Total amount of ram available in my machine is 30 GBs.

Comment: Ah. That's not disk-backed (like I mentioned). I was thinking more of something like https://godbolt.org/z/ThaYEsr31 - Live demo: https://imgur.com/a/oVczaLr

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the results, really appreciate it! Do you think that there will be a performance hit because of using `managed_mapped_file` instead of `managed_shared_memory`.

Comment: Not unless the pages need to be swapped out of RAM. That's dependent on the access patterns. E.g. If you [reduce the size of the runs by 10x](https://godbolt.org/z/E94sr6dGr), observe how the first 8 runs never even commit any dirty pages to disk even though the process is exited and restarted https://imgur.com/a/TeRA3aR. Exactly when pages are synced to disk depends on kernel tuning, ioctls (I think) and of course whether you explicitly `sync`. To drop any caches use [e.g. this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17936/setting-proc-sys-vm-drop-caches-to-clear-cache)

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I was also considering one other approach. I know that I can only grow the shared memory region when all the processes have unmapped the region. I have a working code where I do remap the shared memory region when I grow it. The way this works is that I grow the region but I do not unmap the old pointer. Instead, I do another mmap and keep the old one. The new memory allocations will use this new mmap instead. Do you think there is any way to use any of the boost's managed memory segments on top of this region?

Comment: There's https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_heap_memory_external_buffer

Comment: Does this mean that if I create a `managed_external_buffer` and destroy it and create another `managed_external_buffer` with another pointer (the new mmaped pointer) it is able to still keep track of the allocations even though the `managed_external_buffer` has been recreated.

Comment: My gut reaction is that it would be pretty useless otherwise? Let me defer to previous live example that uses managed_external_buffer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790900/85371. I'm pretty sure I had something to achieve more flexible format versioning and segment growth but can't currently find that.

Comment: Oh look, I found the example I was looking for. I hid it in a lengthy comment thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195435/growing-boost-interprocess-memory-mapped-file-with-single-writer#comment118732629_43201732
Perhaps I should post it as an answer here, so it survives in the future? (Let me know when you see this comment, I think it's pretty important you see the example)

Comment: (Oh, half-face-palm, look *who* I was having that conversation with. Since 2015, through 2019 and now here :))

Comment: Haha :) Thanks for the response @sehe! I have learned a lot from you throughout these conversations. You are correct. The allocations are untouched when you re-map the shared memory region. I think it would be great if you can post the example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct match to the question, but the relevant fruit of the comment thread, here I present an example that uses managed_external_buffer to achieve more control over on-disk format (foreseeing backwards compatible versioning and perhaps some integrity verification) and shows how to implement growth

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/18Thq8qr4)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_external_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>

// sample data structures:
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>

// filesystem stuff
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

// convenience:
static constexpr char const* FILENAME = "data.bin";
static auto operator""_MB(unsigned long long n) { return n << 20; }
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indirected.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/sort.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace fs  = std::filesystem;
using boost::adaptors::indirected;

using Segment                     = bip::managed_external_buffer;
template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Segment::segment_manager>;
using String    = bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
using Database  = bip::vector<String, Alloc<String>>;
using StringPtr = bip::offset_ptr<String>;
using Index     = bip::vector<StringPtr, Alloc<StringPtr>>;

struct MySharedSegment {
    MySharedSegment(bip::create_only_t, char const* filename, size_t size) {
        if (fs::exists(filename))
            throw std::runtime_error("file already exists");
        {
            std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
        }

        grow(filename, size);
        fm = bip::file_mapping(filename, bip::mode_t::read_write);

        auto offset = write_magic_header();

        buf = bip::mapped_region(fm, bip::mode_t::read_write, offset,
                                 size - offset);
        mb  = Segment(bip::create_only, buf.get_address(), buf.get_size());
        auto* mgr = mb.get_segment_manager();

        _vec   = mb.find_or_construct<Database>("vec")(mgr);
        _index = mb.find_or_construct<Index>("index")(mgr);
    }

    MySharedSegment(bip::open_only_t, char const* filename)
    {
        if (!fs::exists(filename))
            throw std::runtime_error("file not found");
        fm = bip::file_mapping(filename, bip::mode_t::read_write);

        auto offset = check_magic_header();
        buf         = bip::mapped_region(fm, bip::mode_t::read_write, offset);

        mb = Segment(bip::open_only, buf.get_address(), buf.get_size());
        if (buf.get_size() > mb.get_size()) {
            // also grow segment if buffer grew
            mb.grow(buf.get_size() - mb.get_size());
        }

        auto [v, vok] = mb.find<Database>("vec");
        auto [i, iok] = mb.find<Index>("index");

        if (!(v && vok && i && iok)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("an expected object was not found");
        }

        _vec   = v;
        _index = i;
    }

    static void grow(char const* filename, size_t extra) {
        fs::resize_file(filename, std::filesystem::file_size(filename) + extra);
    }

    Database& database() {
        assert(_vec);
        return *_vec;
    }

    Index& index() {
        assert(_index);
        return *_index;
    }

    Segment::segment_manager* get_segment_manager() {
        return mb.get_segment_manager();
    }

  private:
    size_t write_magic_header() {
        auto HLEN = v1_magic_header.size();

        if (fs::file_size(fm.get_name()) < HLEN)
            throw std::runtime_error("File short");

        bip::mapped_region mr(fm, bip::mode_t::read_write, 0, HLEN);

        auto out = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(mr.get_address());
        auto nxt =
            std::copy(v1_magic_header.begin(), v1_magic_header.end(), out);
        assert(size_t(nxt - out) == HLEN);
        return HLEN;
    }

    size_t check_magic_header() {
        auto HLEN = v1_magic_header.size();

        if (fs::file_size(fm.get_name()) >= HLEN) {
            bip::mapped_region mr(fm, bip::mode_t::read_only, 0, HLEN);

            if (std::equal(
                    v1_magic_header.begin(), v1_magic_header.end(),
                    reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const*>(mr.get_address()))) {
                return HLEN;
            }
        }
        // TODO future adds newer versions with different on disk formats
        throw std::runtime_error("Unknown database file format");
    }

    bip::file_mapping  fm;
    bip::mapped_region buf;
    Segment            mb;

    Database* _vec   = nullptr;
    Index*    _index = nullptr;

    static constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 16> v1_magic_header = {
        0x27, 0x65, 0xb6, 0xcb, 0x3a, 0x86, 0xf5, 0x48,
        0xba, 0xa3, 0x2c, 0x49, 0x00, 0xdd, 0x6f, 0xde,
    };
};

void create_initial(int size) {
    MySharedSegment mss(bip::create_only, FILENAME, size);

    auto* mgr = mss.get_segment_manager();
    auto& db  = mss.database();

    db.emplace_back("one", mgr);
    db.emplace_back("two", mgr);
    db.emplace_back("three", mgr);

    auto& index = mss.index();
    for (auto& elem : db) {
        index.emplace_back(&elem);
    }

    boost::sort(index | indirected);

    for (auto el : index | indirected) {
        std::cout << el << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void offline_grow_with(int size) { MySharedSegment::grow(FILENAME, size); }

void reopen_and_verify() {
    MySharedSegment mss(bip::open_only, FILENAME);

    // none of the pointers in the index have become invalidated:
    for (auto el : mss.index() | indirected) {
        std::cout << el << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::remove(FILENAME);

    create_initial(1_MB);

    offline_grow_with(1_MB);

    reopen_and_verify();
}
```

Prints

```
one three two 
one three two
```

### Notes

The above still requires/assumes offline growth. You can probably add an interprocess shared mutex in the control headers (outside the managed segment buffer) and use it to do reader-writer locking so other parties automatically unmap the segment when growth is requested.

Comment: I am curious that even the unmapping might not be required. If I keep the `mapped_region` around and make sure that no two processes are simultaneously accessing the memory while the growing is happening, then I think everything should be fine. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree [padding] [padding]